# Adding an existing project to a github repo that already has files

Tags: spring-boot, github, merge

I am a new developer, and am having trouble understanding how to add new content to an existing GitHub repo.  I am working on a SpringBoot app, and my mentor is working on the deployment part with Docker.  I already had a repo on github that was tracking my project, but now we want to use this new repo that he has already put some docker files into.  I tried cloning this new repo down to Intellij, which works fine, but then when I tried to copy original project over into this new clone, it doesn't recognize the classes, so the project will no longer run.

so, in other words, how do I do this:

Github repo 1 (my project) + Github repo 2 (his docker files)--------->Github repo2 (my project with the additional files